# Flutter :I've a problem of context with my dynamics menu

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**I've a problem of build context with my dynamics menu.**

In fact, I want to create a menu dynamically but I don't know how to use the context in _MenuItem's class.

Is there an alternative method?

my code :

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      ...
      body: MenuButtons(kMenuCard),
    );
  }
}

class MenuButtons extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<MenuCard> _menuButtons;

  MenuButtons(this._menuButtons);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: _buildMenu()
    );
  }

  List<_MenuItem> _buildMenu() {
    return _menuButtons.map((button) => _MenuItem(button)).toList();
  }
}
```

In this part my IDE note me : "missing a build context" and Idon't know how to implement the buildContext differently

```
class _MenuItem extends GridTile {

  _MenuItem(MenuCard button)
      : super(
    child:GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){Navigator.push(context, "${button.route}")},
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.teal,
        child: Center(
          child: Text("${button.title}"),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to pass `BuildContext` to Your `_MenuItem` class:

Updated Code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: _buildMenu(context) // Pass Context
    );
  }

List<_MenuItem> _buildMenu(BuildContext context) { 
    return _menuButtons.map((button) => _MenuItem(button,context)).toList();
  }
}

class _MenuItem extends GridTile {

  _MenuItem(MenuCard button,BuildContext context)
      : super(
    child:GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){Navigator.push(context, "${button.route}")},
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.teal,
        child: Center(
          child: Text("${button.title}"),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```